# Angular ui-route base controller extend

Tags: angularjs, extend

I'm really lost. I use ui-route in my angular app and i'm trying to extend my base controller. My base controller (appCtrl) works but child controller (navigationCtrl) doesn't on URL app/welcome. Do you know why???

index.html

```
<body>

    <div id="wrap">

        <!-- View for login and login-choose -->
        <div ui-view="login"></div>

        <!-- View for app -->
        <div ui-view="app"></div>

    </div>

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/app.navigation.js"></script>

</body>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('tvm', ['ui.router', 'ngTouch']);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

// For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

// Set up the states
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: "/",
        views: {
            "login": { templateUrl: "./pages/login.html" }
        }
    })
    .state('login-choose', {
        url: "/login-choose",
        views: {
            "login": { templateUrl: "./pages/login-choose.html" }
        }
    })
    .state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        views: {
            "app": {
                templateUrl: "app.html",
                controller: 'appCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
        .state('app.welcome', {
            url: "/welcome",
            templateUrl: './pages/welcome.html'
        })
        .state('app.profile', {
            url: "/profile",
            templateUrl: './pages/profile.html'
        });

// remove # from URL
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
});
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.parentMethod = function () {
        alert('aaa');
    };
});
```

app.navigation.js

```
app.controller('navigationCtrl', ['$scope', '$controller', function($scope, $controller) {
// extend app controller
angular.extend(this, $controller('appCtrl', {$scope: $scope}));

var nav = $('nav');
var content = $('#content, #bar');
var navWidth = nav.width() + 'px';
var navIcon = $('#bar .nav_icon .circle');

$scope.circleHover = function(e) {
    navIcon.addClass('hover');
};

$scope.circleLeave = function(e) {
    navIcon.removeClass('hover');
};

// open / close nav
$scope.toggleNav = function(e) {

    if(nav.hasClass('visible'))
        closeNav();
    else
        openNav();

};

// when swipe left to right open nav
$scope.openSwipeNav = function(e) {
    openNav();
};

// close nav
$scope.closeNav = function(e) {

    var elem = angular.element(e.target);

    if( (nav.hasClass('visible')) && (!$(elem).is('#bar')) )
        closeNav();
};

// when swipe right to left close nav
$scope.closeSwipeNav = function(e) {
    closeNav();
};

var openNav = function() {
    nav.animate({
        left: 0
    }, 400, function() {
        $(this).addClass('visible');
    });

    content.animate({
       left: navWidth
    }, 400, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('full');
    });

    navIcon.addClass('active');
};

var closeNav = function() {

    nav.animate({
        left: '-' + navWidth
    }, 400, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('visible');
    });

    content.animate({
       left: 0
    }, 400, function() {
        $(this).addClass('full');
        navIcon.removeClass('active');
        navIcon.removeClass('hover');
    });
};
```

}]);

Answer (score 0):

You are providing the states in wrong way should use the below code. It may help you get out of your problem

// Set up the states

```
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
    url: "/",
    views: {
        "login": { templateUrl: "./pages/login.html" }
    }
})
.state('login-choose', {
    url: "/login-choose",
    views: {
        "login": { templateUrl: "./pages/login-choose.html" }
    }
})
.state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    templateUrl: "app.html" //no need to define the controller here. If this route is not usable else define the controller separately for both app and app.welcome
})
    .state('app.welcome', {
        url: "/welcome",
        templateUrl: './pages/welcome.html',
        controller: 'appCtrl' // need to mention the controller in which you wantto perform the functionality of app/welcome
    })
    .state('app.profile', {
        url: "/profile",
        templateUrl: './pages/profile.html'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to solve it by add angular.extend to base controller

```
app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', '$controller', function($scope, $controller) {

        angular.extend(this, $controller('navigationCtrl', {$scope: $scope}));
}]);
```

And I call controller in my first state:

```
.state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        views: {
            "app": {
                templateUrl: "app.html",
                controller: 'appCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
```

Then it also fires navigationCtrl